# Network Thread to communicate with UI Thread

Tags: java, java-threads

I've created a class for multi threading in a Java application.

import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class AppThreads {

```
private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
private static AppThreads sInstance;
private final Executor diskThread;
private final Executor uiThread;
private final Executor networkThread;

private AppExecutors(Executor diskThread, Executor networkThread, Executor uiThread) {
    this.diskThread = diskThread;
    this.networkThread = networkThread;
    this.uiThread = uiThread;
}

public static AppExecutors getInstance() {
    if (sInstance == null) {
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            sInstance = new AppExecutors(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(), Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4),
                    new MainThreadExecutor());
        }
    }
    return sInstance;
}

public Executor diskThread() {
    return diskThread;
}

public Executor networkThread() {
    return networkThread;
}

private static class MainThreadExecutor implements Executor {
    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable command) {
        command.run();
    }
}
```

}

I am initiating a different thread as

```
public void getUsers(AppThreads executors) {
executors.networkThread().execute(() -> {
    //Some DB operations
    //getting server response code  
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
...
...
..
int response=con.getResponseCode();
    }
}
```

How `uiThread` will know the value of `int response` which is being executed in `networkThread`?

Comment: Create event and listener?

Comment: any links for event and listener example in java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution: create some kind of callback, for example:

```
public interface Callback
{
    void done(int response);
}
```

Pass the callback to your `getUsers` method. When you get your response code, you are able to call `callback.done(response)`.

An alternative would be to create some kind of event / listener as @Jure mentionend.